# github actions workflow workflow_dispatch running a workflow manually - most of the Tags are disabled

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, git-branch, git-tag, git-workflow

I am using github actions workflow for code deployment. One of the flow is manual using workflow_dispatch. I am able to select main or any feature branch but when i select tags - most of them are disabled and gives you below error message:

"Workflow does not exist or does not have a workflow_dispatch trigger in this tag.
Learn more about manual workflows"

If I create a new git tag, i am able to deploy. Please help me by sharing the logic and reasoning. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If workflow didn't exist when the tag was created, it's not available. The same goes for branches.

The way to fix it is to either cherry-pick workflow there and move a tag or re-base the tag on top of the `master` branch.

Also keep in mind if you modify workflow on your `master` branch, but you have a different version in branches - it will use the branch / tag version.

If you want to keep 1 version across all tags - you should pass a `tag` as an input variable and run it on `master` branch instead of running workflow on this tag. Then you just have to modify your checkout-action to checkout the passed tag, not leaving it with defaults.

Comment: Thanks. When I create new git tag I am able to deploy. I did try adding a input parameter for tag but it also did not work for tags created before the workflow was created. They should allow us to deploy on older tags. It does work for branches.

Comment: My understanding is that tag is similar to branch. When we use default parameter from github workflow and select a tag I guess its selecting main by default.

Comment: You may want to checkout with all tags option - check fetch-depth

Comment: I am performing fetch-depth: 0 . Thanks for the help.